# in dimensional modeling what are good and bad features/aspects of Grain?

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

i want to know what are good and bad aspects of grain. i have searched for it but i didn't find answer except these points. 
•   The grain determines what each fact record represents: the level of detail. For example Individual transactions, Snapshots (points in time),  Line items on a document
•   Generally better  to focus on the smallest grain
•   It reflects the level of detail in data warehouse
i want to know some more aspects specially bad aspects

Comment: Data inherently has a 'grain' (level of detail). There's nothing good or bad about it. You could say that storing low level detail takes up more space than storing summary detail, but summary detail.... loses detail

Comment: It's like asking about pros and cons of car's color; not the practicality of a white car or a black one, but the fact that a car has a color. It's an inherent property.